# list of all users who watched at least a movie every week in this month

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table active_users(
user_id numeric,
movie_streamed date
)


insert into active_users values (1,'2020-01-2'::date);

insert into active_users values (1,'2020-01-9'::date);

insert into active_users values (1,'2020-01-16'::date);

insert into active_users values (1,'2020-01-23'::date);

insert into active_users values (1,'2020-01-30'::date);

insert into active_users values (2,'2020-01-14'::date);

insert into active_users values (2,'2020-01-16'::date);
```

Hi all,

I am looking for a query which will help me to get the users who watched at least a movie every week in this month(being the test data). Given the data where every record has the user_id and when that particular person has watched the movie given the date. I want a generic answer. Not like every month has 4 weeks. Because there could be some scenarios where there are 5 weeks in some cases too.

Comment: he want us to analyze and complete the function... Pls try to do it and tell us why can't you do that. The logic is: generate extra field to check "how many time user come this week" ~> check if all of it >1. Or you mean > 5 time a month =))

Comment: no I dont want to check the count because there could be 5 weeks too

Comment: I don't know what *you* mean by "month" and "week".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series(1,5)` by counting from 1 upto 5, since there should 5 different weeks might exist even uncompleted as you already mentioned.

The trick is to compare the distinct count of the beginning dates for each week within the current month :

```
SELECT u.user_id  
  FROM active_users u 
  JOIN generate_series( 1, 5 ) g  
    ON date_trunc('week', movie_streamed) 
     = date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '7' day * (g-1) 
 GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date_trunc('week', movie_streamed))  = 
            (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM generate_series( 1, 5 ) g
              WHERE to_char(current_date,'yyyymm') 
                  = to_char(date_trunc('week', current_date) 
                    + interval '7' day * (g-1),'yyyymm')                  
            );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f8ca609cba0838c62ab3dd4c089a7986)</kbd>

Comment: is there any way without using generate series?

Comment: I don't know, but I think this is the shortest way @user10449251 .